# Proportions of different types of nuts in bags of mixed nuts

Tags: goodness-of-fit

Say I wanted to investigate the proportion of different types of nuts in bags of mixed nuts. So I weigh the nuts by type. Would I be able to use the information on weights and the Chi-squared test to analyze the nuts?

Comment: When you say you want to *Say I wanted to investigate the proportion of different types of nuts in bags of mixed nuts* - what do you mean? Do you want to see whether the different types of nuts are equally represented in the bag? Or, are you trying to see whether a particular type of nut is overrepresented? Or, ..?

Comment: I want to see whether the different types of nuts are equally represented

Comment: How many different types are there? How many nuts are in the bag total?

Comment: There are five different types of nuts in the bag

Comment: OK then you are correct that this is a classical $\chi^2$ situation - under the null hypothesis the expected counts are all $.20 \cdot N$ where $N$ is the total number of nuts in the bag, and you can contrast this with the observed counts. Under the null, this statistics has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $4$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Yes, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Wait. Or rather Weight! Is the question about the number of each types of nuts in the bag (in which case the chi-square will do the job as Macro explains) or about the weights (as the original question seems to imply)?

Comment: Instead of counting the nuts, they have been weighed in order to investigate the proportions of the different types of nuts

Comment: @BOB, do you want to see whether the nuts are equally represented in terms of their weight or the number of nuts?

Comment: terms of their weight

Comment: @BOB, ok - I've done a major overhaul of my answer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit:** Based on a modified understanding of the problem, and after a discussion with @whuber (thanks, @whuber), I've modified my approach. My original answer treated the **counts** of nuts as the data, whereas the problem seems to ask how to test whether the different types of nuts are equally represented in terms of **weight**. My last solution (which can be seem by viewing the previous edit) is valid if there is no variation in the size of the nuts but that is probably not a realistic assumption.*

So, my modified understanding of the problem is that you've observed weights - $W_1, ..., W_k$ - of the $k$ different types of nuts and want to see whether or not there is evidence that more of some type of nuts are represented in the bag. That is, you test $$ H_0 : E(W_1) = \cdots  = E(W_k)$$ To solve this problem we have to make some assumptions. Suppose that that average nut size for each type is known - $\mu_1, ..., \mu_k$ - and that the variance in nut size, $\sigma^2$, is the same across types but is unknown. Then we can envision the $W_{i}$'s arising from

$$ W_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} X_{ij} $$

where $X_{ij}$ is size of the $j$'th nut of type $i$ in the sample and $n_i$ is the number of nuts of type $i$ in each bag *(suppose for simplicity that this is the same, but unknown, for all bags, otherwise this becomes a random sum and things are much more complicated)*. Let's assume normality of the nut sizes for brevity (although we could assume any other distribution with a mean and a variance, but we choose the normal here since it is closed under addition)so that $X_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$. Then, assuming individuals nuts are independent, each observed weight of nut type $i$ has a $N(n_i \mu_i, n_i \sigma^2)$ distribution.

Then we can re-formulate the null hypothesis as testing

$$ H_0 : n_1 \mu_1 = \cdots =n_k \mu_k $$

Call this common value $\theta$. Note that, in order to test this hypothesis, we're going to need multiple bags of nuts since we need to estimate the variance and each of the $n_{i}$. Let's say we have $M$ bags and $W_{im}$ is the weight of nut type $i$ in bag $m$.

Under the null hypothesis, $n_i = \theta/\mu_i$ and the joint likelihood is

$$ \prod_{m=1}^M \prod_{i=1}^{k} \phi(W_{im} | \theta, \theta \sigma^{2}/\mu_i) $$

where $\phi(x|\mu,\tau^2)$ is the normal density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\tau^2$, which can be maximized as a function of $\theta, \sigma^2$. Call this optimum $L_0$.

Without the constraint imposed by the null hypothesis, the joint likelihood is

$$ \prod_{m=1}^M \prod_{i=1}^{k} \phi(W_{im} | n_i \mu_i,  n_i \sigma^2) $$

which can be optimized as a function of $n_1, ..., n_k, \sigma^2$. Call this optimum $L_1$.

Now, we can use the usual maximum likelihood machinery, which tells us that

$$ \lambda = 2 \Big( \log(L_1) - \log(L_0) \Big) $$

has an asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution. This is called the likelihood ratio test. The degrees of freedom are $k-1$, since we delete $k-1$ parameters (the $\mu_i$ are replaced by a single parameter $\theta$) to arrive at the submodel. In this example $k=5$.

Comment: The data are *weights,* not counts.

Comment: @whuber, when I posted this, it was under the impression the data were counts. I'm awaiting confirmation from the OP at which time I'll modify/delete.

Comment: Isn't the problem statement quite clear?  Where is the ambiguity?  It might help to know that there is a standard method to count large numbers of small things having a known mean individual weight: just weigh the whole collection and divide by the known weight. Imagine doing this with five collections of nuts and wanting to know whether the resulting five weights are consistent with the hypothesis of equal nut counts: that's what's going on in this question. The reference to chi-squared is a red herring, because it's (obviously) inapplicable.

Comment: @whuber, I guess the ambiguity arose for me in the title and first sentence. Also, I wasn't thinking of "weigh" in terms of weight on a scale, as it usually doesn't mean that in statistics. It seems to me that if you know the weight-per-nut then you can convert the weights to counts and you're back to the answer I gave except you're no longer testing whether the counts are equal - you're testing some other point hypothesis - but you're still using the $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: I disagree with you, Macro, mainly because I'm confident that nuts vary in weight enough for this variation to matter.  If, say, your nuts average 1 gm with an SD of 0.1 gm and the weight is 100 gm, then you likely have between 97 and 103 nuts. This is a small range, to be sure, but it's going to affect the chi-squared test. Better solutions are readily available.  (Use MLE.)

Comment: @whuber, maybe I'm tired today or something but I'm not seeing how we have enough information to characterize the joint distribution of the weights to calculate an MLE without assuming a particular variance of the nut size, which seems just about as arbitrary as what I've done. Can you say a little more or perhaps post it in an answer of your own?